# SSL - How can i secure web browser connections to my private server?

Tags: authentication, encryption, ssh, lamp

I have set up a LAMP server on a Raspberry Pi on my home network. I would like to expose the pi to the internet by opening up ports 22 and 80 on my router so i can ssh into it as well as use any web services i set up on it.

This is a little pet project I'm using to learn more about networking, server setup and linux in general - with only a cheap RPi which i can wipe and start again easily anything goes wrong. I do plan to put it on a separate subnet to the other devices on the home network, just in case.
*(Yes, i know this is a little much for a raspberry pi - this is just a learning exercise and a proof of concept before i throw money at this to build a rig for it)*

My understanding is that SSH is already secure, so i don't have to worry about my username and password being seen across the web when i want a terminal session.

My concern is that if i send anything to a web service (such as a wordpress or phpmyadmin password) it'll be clear to see on the web. How can i stop this?

My plan was SSL, but from what I've read, an SSL certificate needs a domain name for a certificate to be issued by most places. When all I'll be doing is pointing to a static IP from my ISP on the devices I'll be using.

The other use i have planned for it is as a mysql server for my kodi boxes to use for the library data so my devices can share data (the videos live on another server running windows). So other devices on a local network need to be allowed access to mysql easily without the silly level of security the internet-side requires. I assume this will be easily possable alongside my other use cases as I'd not be opening the port for it on the router and the only things that would access msql are local network devices, and services on the mysql host itself

- Are any of my assumptions or conclusions wrong?
- Are there any better ways to achieve what I'm after than what I'm describing?
- Is there a preferred way to interact with the Pi if i just wanted it to set off a specific script? (say send a wake-on-lan packet to a specific computer)
- Is there a way for me to have the web server onllly communicate with specific devices that i have the appropriate keys/certificates loaded onto so that i can be certain that I'm the only one with access?

Comment: Correct. SSL/TLS for the web facing application, everything below DMZ doesn't need it, as you point out. You could find a shared secret encryption protocol and use that if there's only a few clients (depending on what you are trying to do). For certs, you are probably looking for something like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org).

Answer (score 0):

> Are any of my assumptions or conclusions wrong?

Using a username/password combo for SSH is probably secure enough, but it's generally more secure to use a [public/private SSH key pair](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2).

Your assumptions about MySQL seem sound. Just make sure to have some authentication on the server just in case you have a nosey houseguest on your WiFi. :)

> Are there any better ways to achieve what I'm after than what I'm
>   describing?

A couple options that come to mind:

- You could generate a self-signed certificate for the web server and then manually copy that onto your client devices. I think this would allow you to get around the requirement for a domain name.
- You could set up a secure VPN into your home network. This way you wouldn't have to expose your web/SSH servers to the world.

> Is there a way for me to have the web server only communicate with
>   specific devices that i have the appropriate keys/certificates loaded
>   onto so that i can be certain that I'm the only one with access?

- The VPN option mentioned earlier would allow you to do this.
- You could restrict access to the Apache server to only devices with specific client certificates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24543642/2384183

Comment: Everything on the server will require some form of authentication, the pi isn't going to be open, even locally. But you saying that did make me think of wifi sniffing as i am in a block of flats (luckily most of the network is wired though) I'll look into those suggestions.